# $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{x{y^2}}}{{{x^2} + {y^4}}} = 0$ prove by polar coordinates.

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

so we have I have the limit
$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{x{y^2}}}{{{x^2} + {y^4}}}$
Now i know that this limit does not exist. I even saw the proof on this website. However, if you substitute x and y with polar coordinates it seems like the limit exist, to me at least.
$x=rcos(L)$
$y=rsin(L)$
$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{x{y^2}}}{{{x^2} +  {y^4}}}=\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{rcos(L)r^2{sin(L)^2}}}{{{r^2cos(L)^2} + {r^4sin(L)^4}}}=\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{rcos(L)}{cos(L)^2+r^2sin(L)^4}=\frac {0}{cos(L)^2}=0$

I am clearly doing something not allowed. Is it becouse $cos(L)=0$ for some L?

Comment: You've shown the limit is $0$ on any line thru the origin. But there are paths approaching the origin that are not straight lines.

Comment: Why is it only lines? I substituted x and y fpr the polar coordinates. It is just another form of the function, no?

Comment: Try the path $(x,\sqrt x)$ and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah that i know. But i want to know what i did wrong :)

Comment: You assumed $\cos^2 L$ had a nonzero limit. But what if $L \to \pi/2,$  as in the case of $(x,\sqrt x)?$

Comment: Yeah that is what i thought. Thank you very much. Now i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $L$ need not be constant. If we arrange things so that on our path we have $\cos(L)=r$, then the limit will not be $0$.

**Remark:** An argument like yours can be used to show that if $\cos(L)$ and $\sin(L)$ stay bounded away from $0$ as we approach $(0,0)$ along some path, then the limit along that path is $0$.

Comment: So basically what i said? cos(L)=0 hence the limit is not always 0?

Comment: Also, is that a proof that the limit does not exist? or do i have to find 2 different curves and show different limits

Comment: We can arrange the path so that $\cos(L)=r$. This **does not** mean letting $\cos(L)=0$. for that means letting $x=0$, and along the path $x=0$ the limit is $0$. But for small $r$, $L=L(r)$ should be very close to $80$ degrees. An exact condition that works is the one I mentioned, $\cos(L)=r$, though $\cos(L)=5r$ is good too,

Comment: This is not a proof that the limit does not exist, but it is the hard part of the proof. It is easy to find a path along which the limit is $0$. Now we have two different paths of approach to $(0,0)$ that yield different limits, so the "overall" limit does not exist.

Comment: You mentioned that you had already seen proofs of non-existence of the limit. If we did not yet have such a proof, the polar coordinate approach, properly looked at, gives us a lead towards proving the limit does not exist. For it can help us discover what "bad" paths might look like.

Comment: Ok i understand now. Althougn r tends to zero and so "$r=0$". Yup got it. L=pi/2 as zhw. mantioned above.